# Is it possible to make my own DIY one way mirror

Tags: mirror, television

One way glass and perspex is quite expensive.  But regular perspex is not.

I've seen some mirror finish sprays.  Has anyone tried successfully to make a one way mirror using those or perhaps another method?

The purpose of the one way mirror is to put it in front of a flat screen TV that is hanging on my wall.  I want to hide this monstrosity and am open to all ideas.  The mirror idea appeals the most but a professionally made mirror TV is far too expensive.

Comment: Partially silvered glass will seriously reduce the brightness from the TV.  If you really want high tech, use smart glass.  It goes from opaque to virtually clear.  Or you could just hang or place something decorative in front of it that you raise or move to see the TV (like a small shoji panel that swings out of the way).

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't room to swing something out of the way.  But tell me about this smart glass, do you have a link?  sounds expensive though.

Comment: In any case, the TV is only ever watched in a darkish room and this tv can go very bright.  I'd like to experiment with the one way glass.  It's been done before and it's not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: Smart glass would probably be expensive, and I would have to hunt for a DIY product.  But another thought--instead of hiding the TV, turn it into art.  Many TVs have a USB port where you can plug in a flash drive.  You store photos or art images on it and the TV either displays a single picture until you change it, or runs through a collection like a slide show.  I've done that and it's pretty cool.  Bill Gates customizes displayed art in his house by doing this instead of hanging pictures.

Comment: Have the TV display a portrait (that you make in Photoshop).  Using a motion sensor and an Arduino, have the portrait change so the eyes or head follow guests around the room.  Every once in awhile, the person in the portrait gets up and walks out of the portrait and it's an empty chair for awhile.

Comment: @Harper - That's just plain creepy.  I like it. haha.  But no I would rather not have to leave my TV on all the time.  Power is expensive in my part the world.

Comment: @Matt as fixer said turning it into art is an idea worth looking into - make yourself a nice frame like a shadow box for the TV and then let the USB do the trick.

Comment: @Harper awesome ..